# Having trouble with topologies in DirextX

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx, directx-11

Iam trying to draw a quad in DirectX 11, but I have some problems:

```
VERTEX vert[] = {
        {-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
        {0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
        {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},

        {0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
        {5.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
        {-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}
    };
    //0, 1, 2,
    //2, 3, 0

    vbo->Update(vert);
    vbo->Bind();
    deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);
    deviceContext->Draw(6, 0);
```

It draws 3 triangles - one in the correct location, and 2 wrong ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you explicitely specify the triangles, you should use

```
D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST
```

This will consider every 3 vertices as part of the triangle>

In case of triangle strip, you only need to draw 4 vertices, as the drawing will be done using this indexing:

```
Triangle 0->1->2
Triangle 1->2->3
```

The correct array to draw in that case would be :

```
{-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
{0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
{5.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you!